# asp.net chart control showing incorrect tool tip date time value

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, charts

i have written a customized tool tip to shoe the asp.net chart tool tip values, but for some reason the #VALX(x-axis values) which is of date time is being sent wrong to the java script function.

here is my aspx code

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showTooltip(value1, value2, ex) {
            var tooltip = document.getElementById("myToolTip");
            tooltip.style.visibility = "visible";
            var posx = 0;
            var posy = 0;
            if (!e) var e = (window.event) ? event : ex;
            if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
                posx = e.pageX;
                posy = e.pageY;
                tooltip.style.left = posx + "px";
                tooltip.style.top = (posy - 100) + "px";
            }
            else if (e.clientX || e.clientY) {
                if (e.cancelBubble != null) e.cancelBubble = true;
                //for IE8 and earlier versions event bubbling occurs...
                posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
                       + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
                posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
                tooltip.style.left = posx + "px";
                tooltip.style.top = (posy - 100) + "px";
            }
           // document.getElementById("<%=lbl.ClientID%>").innerHTML =
          //"X and Y Values : " + "(" + value1 + "," + value2 + ")";
            document.getElementById("<%=lbl.ClientID%>").innerHTML = "day : " + value1 + " <br> impressions: " + value2 + "";
        }


    function hide() {
        var tooltip = document.getElementById("myToolTip");
        tooltip.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
</script> 
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="MyDropDown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="MyDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Chart runat="server" ID="MyChart" EnableViewState="true">
                        <ChartAreas>
                            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
                        </ChartAreas>
                    </asp:Chart>
    </div>
        <div id="myToolTip" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; width:200px; height:100px; margin: 18px 0;
            padding: 18px 20px;
            background-color: white; /* easy rounded corners for modern browsers */
            -moz-border-radius: 6px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
            border-radius: 6px;
            border: 1px solid #c5d9e8;
            padding: 17px 19px;">
<div style="position:absolute;">
 <b><asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Font-Size="XX-Small"></asp:Label></b>
</div>
</div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this my code behind

```
    //Add the series to the chart
    MyChart.Series.Add(new Series(Seriesname));
    //Define the chart type
    MyChart.Series[Seriesname].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    //MyChart.Titles.Add("Trends shown for time interval of " + SelectedDate);

    //Plot the points on the graph
    MyChart.Series[Seriesname].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
    for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        MyChart.Series[Seriesname].Points.AddXY(Convert.ToDateTime(table.Rows[i].ItemArray[0]), Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[i].ItemArray[1]));
    }

    //adding legends a nd legend style to the chart
    MyChart.Legends.Add(new Legend(Seriesname));
    MyChart.Legends[Seriesname].LegendStyle = LegendStyle.Table;
    MyChart.Legends[Seriesname].TableStyle = LegendTableStyle.Wide;
    MyChart.Legends[Seriesname].Docking = Docking.Bottom;
    MyChart.Legends[Seriesname].IsDockedInsideChartArea = false;

    //Enable view state so that chart is rendered correctly even on the postback
    MyChart.ViewStateContent = SerializationContents.Default;
    MyChart.EnableViewState = true;

    //Adding series attributes to teh charts
    MyChart.Series[Seriesname].BorderWidth = 2;
    MyChart.Legends[Seriesname].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10);
    //MyChart.Series[Seriesname].ToolTip = "Q:#SERIESNAME\nDay:#VALX\nImpressions:#VALY";
    for (int i = 0; i < MyChart.Series[Seriesname].Points.Count; i++)
    {
        MyChart.Series[Seriesname].Points[i].MapAreaAttributes = "onmouseover=\"showTooltip(#VALX,#VALY,event);\"";
    }
    //MyChart.Series[Seriesname].Points[1].MapAreaAttributes = "onmouseover=\"showTooltip(#VALX,#VALY,event);\"";
    MyChart.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "return hide()");
    MyChart.Width = 1500;
    MyChart.Height = 450;
```

the tool tip works fine but the X values which is of type DateTime, instead of showing date it is showing some decimal value(0.0006786458868).

when i use the tootl tip directly like below

```
MyChart.Series[Seriesname].ToolTip = "Q:#SERIESNAME\nDay:#VALX\nImpressions:#VALY";
```

the values shown are correct. i mean the x value in the tool tip shows correct.

any ideas what i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try following.

```
MyChart.Series[Seriesname].Points[i].MapAreaAttributes = "onmouseover=\"showTooltip('#VALX',#VALY,event);\"";
```

Comment: i tried that mit, i even tried #VALX{dd/mm/yyyy}. but it dint work.

Comment: You already set ChartValueType.DateTime so it should work. But please try with XValueType = ChartValueType.String and let me know the result. Please see http://blogs.visoftinc.com/2008/12/15/asp-net-3-5-charting-control-formatting-tooltips-as-date/

Comment: please pass X value between single-quotes and its working onmouseover=\"showTooltip('#VALX',#VALY,event). Also I am editing my answer.

Comment: Thanks a ton mit, can u please explain the significance of the single quote here?

Comment: It's all about formatting  that also I don't know in detail. But I came to know that value should be pass as string after doing 1 hr research.